# Button color after being clicked

Tags: html, css, button, hover, background-color

I used Boostrap to create arrow buttons.I changed the css properties to make sure the background of the buttons are the same as the body background. I also changed the properties to make sure there is no border and that it stays black on hover. The issue is when I click it I get a blue border around and when the mouse in not hovering over it it turns blue. I have tried a bunch of stuff but none is working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        <div id="breakArrows">
            <h6>Session Break</h6>
            <button class="btn btn-info arrowbtn" > <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></button>
            <h4 class="arrownum">1</h4>
            <button class="btn btn-info arrowbtn" ><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
        </div>
         <div id="center">

#break{
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:black;
    float: left;
}

#breakArrows{
    width:10%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:black;
`   float:left;
    padding-left:23px;
    padding-top:175px;
}

.arrowbtn{
    background-color:black; 
    border: none;
    padding-left:33px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.arrowbtn:hover{
   background-color:black;
   border-color: black;
}

.arrownum{
    color:white;
    padding-left:33px;
}

h6{
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Can you please replicate the issue in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](http://codepen.io/) example so we can better help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for offering to help. here is the link to codepen

Comment: http://codepen.io/sammyb123/pen/QyQaPr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very likely you will have to override bootstrap's `:focus` styles as well as `:hover` -- if you simply want the hover and focus styles to be the same you can do this:

```
.arrowbtn:hover, .arrowbtn:focus {
   background-color:black;
   border-color: black;
}
```

otherwise add a separate rule just for `.arrowbtn:focus` and use whatever styles you want it to have. You may also have use for `:active` depending on your design.

Comment: Thank you. that solved half of the problem, there is still the blue border. I tried border:none; but still nothing.

Comment: the blue outline/glow is probably the browser default focus style.  You can try `outline:none;` which will usually override it.  This style is present to help users who navigate sites with a keyboard (usually because of disabilities, etc) know where they are in the page, so it's recommended to replace this style with an alternative style that is more attractive in your design.  That said, many sites do simply eliminate it, and you certainly have that right - I just think it's important to understand the implications.

Comment: You are the man. That did the trick plus I learned something new. Thank you very much.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxyyrB  I forked your pen because I noticed bootstrap's style on :active is more specific, so it was still flashing blue when the mouse is pressed (just for a second while it's 'down').  If you want to get rid of that, you'll have to use something more specific (in my fork, I used the ID of the div wrapping your buttons) as your selector on the `:active`.  it's only affecting one of the sets, but I'm sure you get the idea :-)

Comment: Thanks again. not it looks and behaves the way I wanted it to.

Comment: No problem -- happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

you could declare:

```
<button class="btn btn-info arrowbtn" style="background-color:black!important"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></button>
```

on the button element itself